# What is the difference between [vehicle] and [motor-vehicle]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, Law SE has tags [vehicle](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle) and [motor-vehicle](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motor-vehicle). The latter has no usage guidance. Are they synonyms?

Answer (score 6):

Some vehicles are not motorized or simply don't count as what is defined in a statute as a motor vehicle. For example a horsecart is a vehicle but not motorized. All Motor vehicles are vehicles but not the other way round. There are cases [if a snowmobile is a motor vehicle for statutes, because lawnmowers aren't](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAoEXmUAAyo), [but lawnmower tractors count as such in florida](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWfgL2RyxUc)

An example [from Germany](https://kehl.legal/2010/01/01/ein-pferdefuhrwerk-ist-obwohl-durch-ps-in-bewegung-gesetzt-kein-fahrzeug-im-sinne-der-stvo): the StVO does only partially apply to horse carts like Beer-chariots that are a common sight in some areas in Germany (under § 24 I StVO) making it a **vehicle** but not a **motor vehicle** as it lacks a motor (§ 1 II StVG), resulting in the StVO not applying. However, if the horses damage another vehicle, the owner of the horse is liable as the owner of the animal under the BGB, not the driver of a motor vehicle.

Another example, where vehicles and other vehicles are not the same: [MICHIGAN VEHICLE CODE Act 300 of 1949
Section 257.604](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(tcus55v4tm3gxo1ve5jejors))/mileg.aspx?page=getobject&objectname=mcl-257-604)
:

> A person riding an animal or driving an animal-drawn vehicle upon a roadway shall be granted all of the rights and shall be subject to all the duties, criminal penalties, and civil sanctions applicable to the driver of a vehicle by this chapter, except those provisions of this chapter which by their very nature may not have application.

Illinois has a [special tatract](https://www.chicago.gov/content/dam/city/depts/bacp/rulesandregs/horsedrawncarriagerules03312011.pdf) for non-motorized vehicles, NYC has a [Horse-drawn-cab-license](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/dca/businesses/license-checklist-horse-drawn-cab-driver.page)...

---

## Proposal

Keep the two separate. turn [vehicle](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle) in a way to **not** include cars and other motor vehicles (motorcycles, unicycle) and retag questions about cars with [motor-vehicle](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motor-vehicle)

Comment: True, but we don't live in the 19th century.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Look at the amish, or horse beer carts for advertisement, or on the Oktoberfest...

Comment: Sure, but to have such a specific tag strikes me as odd. How many Amish people post here? Wasn't the 2020 Oktoberfest cancelled?

Comment: I mean, not all vehicles are motor vehices. Some states legislate bicycles as vehicles but not *motor vehicles*. The Oktoberfest might be canceled, but it has regularly sparked damages by horses.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo – this distinction is actually gaining new prominence as law tries to distinguish electric-powered or -boosted scooters and bicycles from "motor vehicles."

Comment: @feetwet I do not understand. Aren't vehicles powered by electric motors considered motor vehicles?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAoEXmUAAyo - Is a snowmobile a motor vehicle?! it's a vehicle, but is it a motor one?! A riding lawnmower is not a motor vehicle.

Comment: @Trish A lawnmower is not a vehicle, is it? I do not understand your point.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo a lawnmower *is* a vehicle, if you drive it on a Florida highway under the influence.

Comment: @Trish If you say so. I am too much of an urbanite to be acquainted with lawnmowers.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Law can define words to mean things that do not comport with common or even literal connotations.  Another example: In the U.S. "firearms" do not include many weapons that propel a projectile by combustion.  E.g., muzzle-loading rifles are not firearms under federal law.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "motorized-vehicle" tag could be made a synonym of the "motor-vehicle" tag.  I have seen the phrase "motorized-vehicle" in a DMV manual before.

I would think that any self-propelled vehicle is not a motor-vehicle.  Certainly bicycles are treated differently by law than mopeds are.

Comment: not all motor propelled vehicles are Motor(ized) vehicles. ATVs and Snowmobiles are not. Boats are not.